# Removing default ul padding/margin

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the default padding on the left of my navigation ul. I've tried setting the #nav ul margins and padding to 0 but that's not working for me. I tried looking for other places where the margins might be affecting the ul, but I can't seem to find anything.

As a note I'm using [Stephen Boyer's Fluid + Responsive Grid Layouts in CSS](http://www.stephanboyer.com/post/41/fluid-responsive-grid-layouts-in-css). I'm not sure if something from that isn't what's tripping me up.

```css
header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#nav {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li.nav_main {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.nav_main a {
  color: #666666;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav_main a:hover,
li.parent:hover {
  color: #F9B585;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.trans {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="span4 phone-hidden" style="background-color:aliceblue;">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="img/logo2.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="span6 phone-hidden" style="background-color:lavender;">
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul id="nav">
          <li class="nav_main"><a class="trans" href="index.html">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav_main"><a class="trans" href="art.html">ART</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav_main"><a class="trans" href="resume.html">R&Eacute;SUM&Eacute;</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="span2 phone-hidden" style="background-color:lemonchiffon;">
      <div id="social_icons">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/chubacca">
          <img src="img/twitter.png">
        </a>
        <a href="http://linkedin.com/pub/alyson-chu/42/690/a57/">
          <img src="img/linkedin.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle? it makes it easier, faster to get help

Comment: `#nav ul` isn't selecting anything because you don't have any `ul` elements inside your `#nav` element. Change `#nav ul` to `ul#nav` if you want to select your unordered list. Or just `#nav` would work, too.

Comment: Yes yes yes! Thanks so much. I was getting so brain-fried staring at this.